# Session variables get lost when redirecting -PHP

Tags: php, variables, session

I am new using PHP and I am trying to build a content management site.

I started developing the login pages and at the start the SESSION variables were kept as normal and were working without any issues when using redirect to another page after login was confirmed.

But 2 days ago i tried to develop the forgot password functionality as well and since then and by only changing the output buffering which i just enabled I have an issue.
The SESSION variables are not carried over to the redirected page and thus the login doesn't work.

My code is below:

```
<?php include("../includes/session.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("../includes/db_connection.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("../includes/functions.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("../includes/validation_functions.php"); ?>
<?php
$username = "";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  // Process the form
  // validations
  $required_fields = array("username", "password");
  validate_presences($required_fields);
      if (empty($errors)) {
        // Attempt Login
            $username = $_POST["username"];
            $password = $_POST["password"];
            $found_admin = attempt_login($username, $password);
            //print_r($found_admin);
                if ($found_admin) {
                  // Success
                        // Mark user as logged in
                        $_SESSION["admin_id"] = $found_admin["usr_serno"];  
                        $_SESSION["username"] = $found_admin["username"];
                        redirect_to("admin.php");
                } else {
                  // Failure
                  $_SESSION["message"] = "Username/password not found.";
                }
        }
}else if(isset($_POST['forgot'])) { 
    redirect_to("forgotPassword.php"); 
 } 
?>
<?php $layout_context = "admin"; ?>
<?php include("../includes/layouts/header.php"); ?>
<div id="main">
  <div id="navigation">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div id="page">
    <?php echo message(); ?>
    <?php echo form_errors($errors); ?>

    <h2>Login</h2>
    <form action="login.php" method="post">
      <p>Username:
        <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo htmlentities($username); ?>" />
      </p>
      <p>Password:
        <input type="password" name="password" value="" />
      </p>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
      <input type="submit" name="forgot" value="Forgot Password" />
    </form>

  </div>
</div>

<?php include("../includes/layouts/footer.php"); ?>
```

the session.php starts the session 
and the admin.php will just check if the SESSION[admin_id] isset then it will show the page or else it will redirect again to login.php page, which is what happens.

Any advise or help please?

Comment: Have you tried echoing the value of `$_SESSION["admin_id"]` before redirecting to check if it has the value you expect?

Comment: What's in session.php? the call to session_start()? You should put that at the top of every page that is actually hit, not inside pages that are includes.

Comment: I did echo SESSION value and before redirecting I am getting the id... but as soon as the redirection occurs its lost it doesn't transfer the value.... session.php is the session.start() yes.I checked that and I do have in every page that

Comment: Depending on certain configurations you may need to add this before session_start():  `session_save_path("your home directory path"/somedirectory/tmp);`  Worth a shot anyway.

Comment: Tried session_save_path("home directory temp") still the same issue... session variable is not transferred when redirecting to another page.

Comment: just to add .. just checked the logs from the tmp wamp folder and i can see that the admin.php is hit with a GET request but the answer is 302 unfortunately... any comments on the above issue are more than welcome as I am new to php and am trying to reach the deadline :(

Comment: any more ideas guys anyone that can help for this issue